# What is the name of this summation formula?

Tags: summation, arithmetic

So recently I derived a formula (obviously not the first... it already existed but that is what got me into summations) that quickly adds all the numbers from 1 to "n" However I recently derived another formula (also not the first I am guessing) that adds all the numbers from any number (not just 1) to "n" (i.e. 14+15+16+17)

Where i= Starting number and n= Ending number

$$\sum_{i}^{n} = \left ( n-i+1 \right )\ast \left ( \left ( n+i \right )/2 \right )$$

What I want to know is what is this formula called? Mine is very complicated looking as well so is there a more compact way?

Comment: Not every formula has a name.

Comment: The first formula would be the triangle numbers. Not sure how a floor managed to sneak into your second formula, though? Unless those square brackets are just for grouping.

Comment: Yeah sorry @DustanLevenstein the squre brackets were just for grouping, making it easier to see, but I have changed it.

Comment: I see you prefer your TeX in the nude?

Comment: The closest thing this formula has an "official" name is just "The Arithmetic Series" formula. Though it is certainly known affectionately as "Gauss's Trick" among mathematicians, probably the only eight year old with a theorem named for him.

Comment: @DustanLevenstein yeah I am not sure why the code is not showing up like it should? How do I change this?

Comment: By reintroducing the pair of dollar signs, which Jack M was so kind as to add to your post, and which you removed in your last edit! ;-)

Comment: @DavidH Yes this would be "Gauss's Trick" if the equation started at 1 (i.e. 1+2+3+4) but this one works starting at any number (and if I am correct I do not think 'Gauss's Trick' works if the starting number is not 1)

Comment: @BenT Gauss's Trick works for any arithmetic series, meaning that if you take an arithmetic series and add it term-wise to its reverse, then you will get a constant series.

Comment: @DustanLevenstein tell me if I am correct Gauss's trick is this: ∑=(n(n+1)/2

Comment: I've fixed your post. Gauss's trick was a clever way to sum up the first $100$ natural numbers, but the same trick works for any arithmetic series.

Comment: But how could Gauss's Trick work say if you wanted to sum up the numbers from 200-300? There is only one variable in the equation "n" which is the ending number because it automatically assumes you are starting at 1? If you could help me understand how would you use the Gauss Trick to find the summation of the numbers from 200-300?

Comment: @BenT Use Gauss's trick to sum from 1 to 300. Then use Gauss's trick to sum from 1 to 199. Subtract the results. It's a fairly trivial extension.

Comment: The trick is illustrated under "Sum" on Wikipedia here: http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arithmetic_progression

Comment: So technically my equation is less work than using "Gauss's Trick" twice right :D ? @DavidH

Comment: To use Gauss's trick to sum the numbers from 200–300, note that 200+300 = 201+299 = 202+298 = … = 249 + 251.  There are 50 such pairs, each totaling 500, and the number 250 is left over in the middle.  Thus the total is $50\cdot500 + 250 = 25250$.

Answer (score 1):

I think this is Gauss' summation trick. Not sure if it has an official name, however.

Answer (score 1):

Let's suppose we want to add the numbers from $a$ to $b$.  There are several ways to approach this.  One way is to observe that there are $b-a+1$ numbers, and each one, on average is $\frac12(a+b)$, so the total is the product of these, $$\frac12(b-a+1)(a+b).\tag{1}$$  This is exactly your formula. We might expand the multiplication of the two terms, obtaining $$\frac12(b^2-a^2+a+b).\tag{2}$$

Using the Gauss trick, one can pair up the numbers into $$\begin{align} a&+b,\\ (a+1)&+(b-1),\\(a+2)&+(b-2)\\&\vdots\end{align}$$ obtaining pairs that each total $a+b$. There are $b-a+1$ numbers in the range, so $\frac12(b-a+1)$ such pairs.  (Note that if $b-a+1$ is odd, this correctly accounts for the extra “half” of a pair.)  So the total is the product of these, again $\frac12(b-a+1)(a+b)$, which is formula (1) again.$

Here's another method.  Suppose we already know that $$1+2+\ldots+n = \frac12(n^2+n).\tag{3}$$  Then to sum the numbers from $a$ to $b$ we find the sum of the numbers from $1$ to $b$, which is $$\frac12(b^2+b).$$ From this we must take away again the sum of the numbers from $1$ to $a-1$, which is $$\frac12((a-1)^2+(a-1))$$  obtaining the total  $$\frac12(b^2+b) - \frac12((a-1)^2+(a-1))$$ which simplifies to $$\frac12\left(b^2+b-a^2+a\right)$$ which is formula $(2)$ again.

Here's yet another method.  Note that if were were to subtract $a$ from each term of $a, a+1, a+2, \ldots, b$, we would obtain $0,1, 2, 3, \ldots, b-a$. Formula (3) tells us that the sum of these is $$\frac12((b-a)^2 + (b-a)).$$
But to this we have to add back the $a$'s we took away; there are $b-a+1$ of these, so the complete total is  $$\frac12((b-a)^2 + (b-a)) + a(b-a+1)$$
which, if we work out the algebra, gives us $(2)$ again.

In short, there are a lot of ways to get the same answer, which has been known for a long time.

Comment: Oh yes no doubt I agree there are different ways to reach the same answer (thanks btw for showing me another way) I was just asking what it was called, I was not trying to claim that I was the first person to find it haha.